# Can't stop Git tracking a .gitignore'd file

Tags: git

I have a file in a remote repository (BitBucket) that I don't want Git tracked, but I do want it to be part of the repository. When pulling that repo to a local computer this file needs to be pulled too. However, I don't then want local users to push changes (i.e. I don't want Git to track it).

I add that file to `.gitignore`. However, it just won't ignore it. I think it might be something to do with the fact that it is part of the repository as any other file would be ignored (e.g. if I create a random file and add it to .gitignore it IS ignored).

I have tried everything on this page: http://365git.tumblr.com/post/519016351/three-ways-of-excluding-files but it just won't stop tracking it.

This is the only thing that works but isn't very user friendly and I've heard that the changes might actually be committed, just not visible in the staging area (when doing a git status):

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [file]
```

Regardless, I just need a way of having a file in a remote repository (GitHub/BitBucket) that can be pulled but not edited, updated or monitored by Git. Is it possible?

Comment: I can remember some (maybe not all?) Git versions are able to handle this. Commit file, .gitignore it and it will stay put. Interesting here is: which **Git version** are you using? Whats the **`.gitignore` line** for the file? What's the **path**? You might guess it: maybe the .gitignore does not match the path? See [the gitignore man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore). Does this behaviour also occure on a local *<strike>remote</strike> bare repsoitory* or only on BitBucket? (Maybe you might add `[bitbucket]` to the tags)

Comment: If it's in the remote repository as a checked in file, *it is not ignored*. Whether it's on your machine or on the remote one doesn't matter. You're asking for something and it's opposite at the same time. Not possible.

Comment: @try-catch-finally, no, adding a tracked file to `.gitignore` never prevents changes from being committed. Git's ignores are purely to prevent files from being tracked (i.e., to make sure that they don't get initially `add`ed). Once a file is part of the repository, nothing in `.gitignore` will have any effect on it.

Comment: @Chis: I'm sure I used a version once that was able to do this. At least pre Git 1.8, but more likely another Git implementation like JGit (using EGit in Eclipse). I've just tested it with Git `v1.8.1.4` and you're right, once commited, .gitiginoring it does not work. (nod) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git will *never* ignore files that were added explicitely, and Git’s ignore list only applies to *untracked* files.

So as soon as you add the file to the repository, the `.gitignore` contents are ignored for that file. There is no way around this, and it makes a lot of sense that it works this way. It’s simply not possible to make Git ignore a file but track it at the same time. The only way to tell Git to ignore changes to it afterwards is to use `update-index --assume-unchanged`.

The usual way to handle this use case, that is having some kind of default configuration inside the repository but allow users to customize it without having those customizations in the repository again, is to use one of two ways to handle it: One is to specify an *example* configuration file. So instead of adding e.g. `config.ini` to the repository, you add `config.example.ini` to it and ask users to copy it manually to `config.ini` before making their custom changes. `config.ini` itself is ignored so it won’t be added to the repository. The other way is to specify multiple levels of configuration. For example you have a `config.ini`—which is in the repository and contains the default configuration—and also load a `config.user.ini` with your application which makes it possible to overwrite settings. That `config.user.ini` is again ignored and a user can create it manually if they want to change their own configuration.